# Strange behavior in GZIPOutputStream/GZIPInputStream

Tags: java, gzipinputstream

I have reduced the strange issue in this code to the minimum. This program writes 128,000 times the bytes for (int)90000 into a file and then tries to read it back in.

set zipped=false and everything works like a charm
set zipped=true and everything works like a charm until the 496th chunk of 1024 bytes. At that point a single byte is lost and everything is shifted to the left by one byte (see output)

...
0 1 95 -112- which is byte code for int 90,000
Counters: 496 126937
1 95 -112 0- which is byte code for int 23,040,000
...

this is the code i came up with. I just can't figure out why it suddenly breaks in the middle of doing the same thing over and over. Any help/insights/explainers much appreciated.

```
public class TestApp7 {

static final boolean    zipped = true;
static File             theFile = null;

private static void writeZipData() throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    if (zipped) {
        GZIPOutputStream gzout = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(gzout);
    } else 
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    byte[] bs9 = RHUtilities.toByteArray((int)90000);
    for (int i=0; i<128000; i++)
        bos.write(bs9);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
}

private static void readZipData() throws Exception {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int chunkCounter = 0;
    int intCounter = 0;
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(theFile);
    int rdLen = 0;
    if (zipped) {
        GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(fin);
        while ((rdLen = gin.read(buf)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("Counters: " + chunkCounter + " " + intCounter);
            for (int i=0; i<rdLen/4; i++) {
                byte[] bs = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf,(i*4),((i+1)*4));
                intCounter++;
                System.out.print(bs[0] + " " + bs[1] + " " + bs[2] + " " + bs[3]);
            }
            chunkCounter++;
        }
        gin.close();
    } else {
        while ((rdLen = fin.read(buf)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("Counters: " + chunkCounter + " " + intCounter);
            for (int i=0; i<rdLen/4; i++) {
                byte[] bs = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf,(i*4),((i+1)*4));
                intCounter++;
                System.out.print(bs[0] + " " + bs[1] + " " + bs[2] + " " + bs[3]);
            }
            chunkCounter++;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        if (zipped)
            theFile = new File("Test.gz");
        else
            theFile = new File("Test.dat");
        writeZipData();
        readZipData();
    } catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
}
```

Comment: Your loops using `rdLen` assumes it's always a multiple of 4. That seems to me to be a dangerous assumption.

Comment: i understand. i did this here to show the problem i ran into. the code in this case only writes out and reads in 4 byte ints.

Comment: That doesn't mean that a call to `read` will always return a multiple of 4 bytes though. Maybe it will if you're lucky, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: tx jon. maybe i am misunderstanding the inner workings then. my reading of the documentation says that GZIPInputStream.read fills the provided 1024 byte buffer with the next 1024 bytes from the stream (which i then Arrays.copyOfRange in 4 byte chunks and coerce into ints). are you saying that GZIPInputStream.read may fill the provided buffer only partially?

Comment: Yes, just like every other `InputStream`. The `GZipInputStream.read` docs: "If len is not zero, the method will block until **some** input can be decompressed" (emphasis mine). You should *never* assume that a stream reads all the data you've asked for... the one exception I usually make to that is if it's a `ByteArrayInputStream` and I know that there's enough data to fill the buffer. I'm not saying that *is* the problem here, but your code is certainly making an inappropriate assumption.

Comment: wow, you are right, i am reporting out rdLen now and only that one iteration reads 869 bytes instead of 1024, all the ones before and after are back to 1024. Am I causing this with the way i am writing it out? always happens at exactly the same spot

Comment: Probably just an artifact of the decompression. It doesn't mean anything's wrong - that's just how you need to understand streams work. It's *particularly* noticeable with network-based streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on Jon's wonderful comments ... you cannot rely on .read(buffer) filling the buffer even when there are more bytes in the stream - it stops at the boundary where the BufferedOutputStream-wrapped GZIPOutputStream saved a chunk of data. just add another read to go beyond the boundary and complete the chunk

```
        while ((rdLen = gin.read(buf)) != -1) {
            if (rdLen<chunksize) {
                byte[] missBytes = new byte[chunksize-rdLen];
                int rdLine_miss = 0;
                if ((rdLine_miss = gin.read(missBytes)) > 0)
                    System.arraycopy(missBytes,0,buf,rdLen,rdLine_miss);
                rdLen += rdLine_miss;
            }
            for (int i=0; i<rdLen/4; i++) {
                byte[] bs = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf,(i*4),((i+1)*4));
                intCounter++;
                System.out.println(bs[0] + " " + bs[1] + " " + bs[2] + " " + bs[3] + " ");
            }
            chunkCounter++;
        }
```